# Analysing and Reporting ordinal logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-data

was wondering if anyone could help. Sorry if this question has been asked before - cannot find it anywhere

I am running multiple ordinal logistic regressions using R, using the "ordinal" package, and CLM function. It produces and output table like this one:
[image]

Output wihtout the interaction:
[image]

From this, and a few additional follow up tests, this is how I have interpreted this: 
There was no main effects of timing on juror confidence in their verdicts (p= 0.740) (before, M=6.31 , SD= 2.08) (after, M= 6.45 , SD= 2.15) or complexity of the expert testimony (p= 0.329) (standard: m=6.10, SD=2.22) (scientific: m=6.70, SD =2.01). However, there was an interaction between complexity and timing (p= 0.018). Further analysis found that confidence would go up by 1.306 if the expert testimony was presented before the eyewitness account, regardless of the complexity of the testimony.

However, I am unsure how to report this results for a statistical paper, using this output. For example, I do not have any degrees of freedom?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the output for the model without interaction as well? When the interaction is present, the interpretation (and inference) of the first order effects (`standardsci` and `afterbef`) depends on their center and scale.

Comment: @AdamO do you mean, conduct the model without the interaction included? Sorry if that is a silly question

Comment: In the `clm` procedure where you pass the formula `confidence.order ~ standardsci + afterbef + standardsci:afterbef`, delete `standardsci:afterbef` and rerun.

Comment: @AdamO added :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1. Always interpret the model *without* interactions first. Then describe the effect of the interaction. For instance, the stopping distance of a car interacts with the weight of the car with the speed it's traveling. If you fit an interaction between these, the "main effects" are 0, but surely you can't report something silly like "speed and weight were not associated with stopping distance."
2. "Main effects" and "interactions" are jargon for a non-statistical audience.
3. Don't "accept the null hypothesis" (you write "there were no main effects"). Your study is probably underpowered.
4. Use a contextually correct description of the predictors. "After/before" means in relation to...? I'm assuming the delivery of the verdict or sentencing?
5. Report the actual coefficients and their 95% CIs instead of the qualitative p-value.
6. Exponentiate the "Estimate" column for a cumulative odds ratio. For instance, "afterbef" = exp(-1.251) $\approx$ 0.29. So you can say, "The odds ratio for a higher juror confidence was 0.87 before sentencing was delivered."

Comment: thank you for that. Can I ask where you got the  "≈  0.87" from? Just so I can understand what you did?

Comment: @EmilyWest that was a typo. It should be noted that the order of magnitude of that effect is insanely large, but without understanding how it's coded I can't say much more. Is it really a binary value?

Comment: the dv was a likert scale, rather than verdict (did a multinomial regression for my verdict DV was it had 3 levels)

Comment: @EmilyWest Don't think I said as much. I'll leave it to you to be as clear as possible in your description of regressors and of outcomes. In general, the cumulative odds ratio is reported as "odds ratio of a higher (response: juror confidence?) was 0.87 comparing (positive exposure: before XXX?) to (negative exposure: after XXX?)